# how to pick and get real URL from my gallary android to send string to API useing retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, woocommerce-rest-api

please how can get real uri like: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/list-2.svg
from my gallary in android

I've tried several methods but I get likee this:  `CONTENT://COM.ANDROID.PROVIDERS.MEDIA.DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/IMAGE%3A786188`

My problem is that my API needs a string to place an image

```
"images": [
{
  "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_4_front.jpg"
},
```

i useing Retrofit

so please How can I solve this problem
I hope for your help

Comment: "please how can get real uri like: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/list-2.svg from my gallary in android" -- if you wish to have an HTTPS URL for an image that resides on the phone, you will need to upload the image to a Web server.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking through another method like local host in android

Comment: i used firebase to uplaod the image or drobox....,and you will get web link